# While downloading a file over 300 mb, if user did enter background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, afnetworking

i'm developing an video download application but there is a problem. User did enter background (while downloading), after several minutes ago, when user did call back application from background, the downloading file get a problem. For example, the file must resume from (for example) 34%. it resumes but downloading completing on 134% !? in other words, i get %100 of the file but, on %134. is anybody have an idea? Sorry for my bad english.

- Below, there are my codes i used, got from AFNetworking ;

  ```
  [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);

  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);       

  }];
  ```
- To see percentage of the file, i use following codes;

  ```
  [[MUtility sharedObject].operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

       NSLog(@"Download = %f", (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead *100);

  }];
  ```

Comment: so did they download 134% of the file (e.g. the original 34% and then the whole file again?) Or are you just DISPLAYING 134% total, but they really only have 100% of the file?

Comment: Yes exactly.. it starts from %0 but show me resuming on %34. and at the end, it finish on %134.. 
In other words, i got %100 of the file but shows me %134